# comparing bitwise operators

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

```
gcc 4.7.2
c89
```

Hello,

```
enum message_e {
    SIP_CONNECTED = 1 << 0,
    CALL_ACCEPTED = 1 << 1
};
```

Setting the bits in different parts of my code:

```
channel->base.message |= CALL_ACCEPTED;
channel->base.message |= SIP_CONNECTED;
```

Later I want to check to make sure both bits are set:

```
if((channel->base.message & SIP_CONNECTED) && (channel->base.message & CALL_ACCEPTED)) {
    /* IF BOTH BITS ARE SET CALL_ACCEPTED and SIP_CONNECTED */    
}
```

I only want to fall through the if statement if ONLY those bits are set. If CALL_ACCEPTED is set and SIP_CONNECTED is not and vice versa.

However, it seems to fall through into the if-statement if only one of them is set.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: What are the values of those defines ?

Comment: Whatever is wrong with your program is not in the code you posted.

Comment: Assuming those are distinct bits sets that have no overlap, this code is correct. What are the values of those bit masks?

Comment: The problem was when I initialized I set the parameter like this: channel->base.message = -1; I guess that set all the bits. I have not changed it to channel->base.message = 0; Just follow-up question what is the best way to reset all the bits?

Comment: @ant2009, set channel->base.message=-1 is the reason you got this problem, -1 means 0xffffffff.And assigning the value to zero is same as resetting all the bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you check CALL_ACCEPTED and SIP_CONNECTED macro?Are they conflict with each other?For example:

```
CALL_ACCEPTED is 0x01 and SIP_CONNECTED is 0x11.
```

After your code:

```
channel->base.message |= CALL_ACCEPTED;
channel->base.message |= SIP_CONNECTED;

channel->base.message = 0x11;
```

So `if((channel->base.message & SIP_CONNECTED) && (channel->base.message & CALL_ACCEPTED))`
is always true.That is my analysis

Comment: My mistake see my question commit above.

Comment: @ant2009, ok, and have you set channel->base.message to zero before you set those flags?Maybe before you set those flags, it has already those flags.

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct

The code into the `if` is executed only if both  `CALL_ACCEPTED` is set and `SIP_CONNECTED` is set

may be before the check you done you have an error in your code and the  `CALL_ACCEPTED` or `SIP_CONNECTED` is not set correctly

check just before the `if` that both  `CALL_ACCEPTED` and `SIP_CONNECTED` are set correctly.

You can check it with debug or with `printf`

Comment: My mistake see my question commit above

Comment: Nothing is changed in the question ?!

Answer (score 0):

Its the binary AND **operator &** that is required. && is the logical and operator.

```
if((channel->base.message & SIP_CONNECTED) & (channel->base.message & CALL_ACCEPTED)) {
```

Comment: Why wouldn't a logical AND work? A bit wise operation would do quite the opposite in this case.